# Javascript / jquery - Re-allow opening a modal after hiding it

Tags: javascript, jquery, hubspot

I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7385673/1467802) to hiding a modal after I clicked outside it.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".messenger");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }

});
```

In the comments, somebody rightfully said that you have to add something, if not you can't open the modal again after it has been hidden once

> Remembering to use $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR").unbind( 'click',
>   clickDocument ); just beside .hide(). So document don't keep listening
>   for clicks. – brasofilo

So I added a line

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".messenger");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
        container.unbind( 'click', clickDocument );//THE LINE I ADDED
    }

});
```

But it does not work. If I click again the button, the modal does not reappear anymore.

Rookie in javascript. am I doing something wrong ?

**EDIT**

The script managing the opening of the modal is not custom. I use hubspot Messenger:

So I only write this code.

```
var msg;
msg = Messenger().post({
  message:      'this si message inside modal',
  hideAfter:    2500,
  showCloseButton: true,
  type: 'skip'
});
```

Comment: can you please show the script handler that opens the container on click?

Comment: it's handled by Hubspot Messenger library - http://github.hubspot.com/messenger/ so i did not write it myself.

Comment: Hiding would'nt be an appropriate way to close modals. There should be some way to trigger closing modal manually. You should use that

Comment: haha looked for it, but only found this. most literature talk about closing jquery UI modal dialogs which is not what I use. Open to suggestions.

Comment: just tried '.remove' instead of .hide. It really removes it from the DOM. Still the same problem: if I re-click on the button, the modal/alert does not appear any more.

Comment: just tried .empty and it worked now. Don't ask me why. Some conflicts with hubspot Messenger maybe.

Comment: Glad to see you got it working - I just wanted to mention that if you or anyone else is using Bootstrap modals and are having problems with them, here is a library that expands upon the basic Bootstrap Modals and fixes a lot of the quirks. I use the addon anytime that I build a Bootstrap site that is going to require Modals.

https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal